# Shut Down Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: shutdown

I am trying to use Ubuntu 14.04 on Acer (I have recently installed it on Windows 8.1), but  have the problem with shutdown. It is not possible to shutdown Ubuntu by clicking on (Shut Down). I have tested (sudo reboot) on terminal, which is working correctly; but (sudo shutdown -P now) and (sudo poweroff) are not shutting down the laptop through terminal. It seems that laptop is going to hibernate condition. I have to use the power button to shutdown the laptop. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you could give this a try:

Boot into Windows 8.1 and disable the fast boot feature which puts Windows into hibernate. This 'may' fix it.

Also make sure if your installation is a separate partition (eg: has GRUB bootloader?)  If you installed the software based version of Ubuntu (eg: installed in Windows) then it is just running Windows and emulating it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo halt --force -p`

Since you are running 14.04 which uses the upstart system management toolset `halt`, `reboot`, and `poweroff` are all one program, that normally chains to shutdown; unless the --force option is used, which makes it make the reboot() system call itself.

[Source:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/what-is-the-difference-between-halt-and-shutdown-commands)

Answer (score -1):

you can create a .desktop file, that shut down the computer when started. start text editor and write
**[Desktop Entry]

Name=ShutDown

Exec=sudo reboot -p

Terminal=true

Type=Application**

**note: you can add icon by write Icon:directory/to/the/icon

*note: you can have terminal=false, but i recommend to have it at true, because if something goes wrong, you can see whats happening*

and save it as Shutdown.desktop

its dont solve the bug, but its give you a program on your desktop that you can use :D.

Note: When  called  with  --force or when in runlevel 0 or 6, this tool invokes the reboot(2) system call
       itself (with REBOOTCOMMAND argument passed) and directly reboots the system.  Otherwise this simply
       invokes the shutdown(8) tool with the appropriate arguments without passing REBOOTCOMMAND argument.

Comment: This does not solve the problem and you know it. So why post this?

Comment: its true that this isnt solve the problem, but at least, its can give you an alternate to shut down your computer

Comment: OP's problem is that the system does not shut down. OP does not need alternative ways that do not work either.

Comment: can you tell me, why are you everywhere near my questions, answers?

Comment: It is accidentally. Nothing personal ;-) I sugest reading the guide how to ask and answer at this site.